# Are AD Users and Windows User technically the same?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Are the Windows Users and the AD Users technically the same ?
Can a windows users list have users who do not belong to the AD Users List ?
Or can AD Users List have users who do not belong to the windows users ?

Comment: maybe I misunderstand what you mean with windows users list but you can have local users on a windows computer that are basically the same as on any not domain joined computer would have so they would definitely not be listed in any ad list

Comment: Maybe this is off topic here I suggest you to ask on serverfault or superuser and close this post.